# Custom shortcuts not working when program minimised

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I am using Linux Mint 18. I have used [this](http://forum.getnightingale.com/thread-426.html) advice to install a custom play/pause key for Nightingale. I was pleased to find it worked, but then after minimising Nightingale, or bringing other programs on top of it on screen, the custom shortcut no longer worked. This is not ideal, and I am hoping someone can recommend an easy fix so that the shortcut works the play pause, no matter what position Nightingale is in.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xbindkeys`, it makes global key shortcuts.

```
DESCRIPTION
       XbindKeys  is a program that grab keys and mouse button events in X and
       starts associated shell command.
```